# How to send a person to a 404 page if f:viewParam / converter returns null?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, http-status-code-404, converters

Lets say you had a page with a view param, like `/widgets?widgetId=1`

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam
            name="widgetId"
            value="#{widgetIdMB.widgetId}"
            converter="#{widgetIDConverter}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

So, less say your converter throws a `ConverterException`, because someone tried to navigate to  `/widgets?widgetId=1000000`, which doesn't exist in the database. Is there a way to send the person to the 404 page when that happens?

EDIT:

I used a converter to convert the value. If the value can't be looked up in the database, the converter returns null, rather than throwing a ConverterException.

Then I use a validator. The validator will throw a validationexception, but not after calling the omnifaces utility class: `Faces.responseSendError(404, "Not Found");`

This seems like the best implementation of separation of concerns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ExternalContext#responseSendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#responseSendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) in the `Converter` when the condition is met.

```
context.getExternalContext().responseSendError(404, message);
context.responseComplete();
return null;
```

Don't forget to call `FacesContext#responseComplete()` afterwards, this isn't implicitly been done for some reason, in contrary to `ExternalContext#redirect()`. Otherwise JSF will append the current page to end of response, or throw an `IllegalStateException` when it's already committed.

Instead of the magic number `404` you can also use [`HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#SC_NOT_FOUND).

```
context.getExternalContext().responseSendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, message);
context.responseComplete();
return null;
```

Comment: I did this separate from the converter, in a validator. Essentially if the converter converts to null, the validator sends the 404 and responseComplete().

Comment: That can also and does indeed make more sense.