# How can I integrate SSO authentication with JSF?

Tags: jsf, authentication, jsf-2, filter, single-sign-on

I'm currently using a Filter to check for SSO authentication.  (SSO is considered authenticated if the request header contains the variable "Proxy-Remote-User").

```
if (!(isSsoLoggedIn(request)) {
    response.sendRedirect(ERROR_PAGE);
    return;
} else {
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

private boolean isSsoLoggedIn(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request != null && request.getHeader("Proxy-Remote-User") != null
            && !request.getHeader("Proxy-Remote-User").equals("");
}
```

Now, once the user is authenticated, I want to pass that variable (which is an email address) to JSF.  I do that with a session-scoped bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaderMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap();
    String email = requestHeaderMap.get("Proxy-Remote-User");
    user = getPersonFromDB(email);
}
```

This seems simple enough, but I'm not sure if its the "right" way to do this.  It doesn't seem correct to rely on a bean's instantiation to verify authentication.

**One idea I just had:** Use a CDI session-scoped bean and @Inject it into the Filter.  Then, you could have the filter itself check for a valid user and, if valid, set it in the session-scoped bean, otherwise forward it to an error page.

Does that sound like a valid solution?

**Another approach** could be to have every page check for authentication, before the view is rendered, with a view param as mentioned here:

[JSF calls methods when managed bean constructor sends 404 ERROR CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636489/jsf-calls-methods-when-managed-bean-constructor-sends-404-error-code)

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.checkForValidUser}" />
</f:metadata>
```

The only problem I have for this is...this would require copying/pasting the same code to every page which seems redundant (or at least a template for them all to use).

Comment: Do you have CDI at hands?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using ManagedBeans but we have a goal to convert to CDI in the future.  I haven't looked into the procedure yet but, if its pretty easy, I could probably convert to them to get this to work.

Comment: If I can convert to CDI, are you suggesting that my CDI-solution above would be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with (thanks to some tips from @BalusC).

I check to see if developer login is enabled or SSO has been authenticated.  Once I have the email address, I see if its a valid user, verify the JSF session contains the right user, and, if so, forward them on their way.

```
/**
 * This filter handles SSO login (or developer login) privileges to the web
 * application.
 */
@WebFilter(servletNames = "Faces Servlet")
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    @EJB
    private PersonWriteFacadeRemote personFacade;

    private HttpServletRequest currentRequest;
    private HttpServletResponse currentResponse;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        currentResponse = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = currentRequest.getSession();
        String requestedPage = currentRequest.getRequestURI();

            // check if the session is initialized
        // if not, initialize it
        if (!isSessionInitialized()) {
            Person user = getCurrentUser();

            // if we can't figure out who the user is, then send 401 error
            if (user != null) {
                initializeSession(user);
            } else {
                currentResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }

                // if it is initialized, check if it actually matches the current
            // user
            // if not, invalidate the session and redirect them back to the page
            // to reinitialize it
        } else if (!isSessionCurrentUsers()) {
            session.invalidate();
            currentResponse.sendRedirect(requestedPage);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res); // If all looks good, continue the request

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    private Person getCurrentUser() {
        try {
            return personFacade.createFromEmail(getUserEmail());
        } catch (InvalidAttributesException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SecurityFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String getUserEmail() {
        return isDevLoginEnabled() ? getUserEmailFromJndi() : getUserEmailFromSso();
    }

    private String getUserEmailFromJndi() {
        return JNDI.lookup("devLoginEmail");
    }

    private String getUserEmailFromSso() {
        return currentRequest != null && currentRequest.getHeader("Proxy-Remote-User") != null
                && !currentRequest.getHeader("Proxy-Remote-User").equals("")
                        ? currentRequest.getHeader("Proxy-Remote-User") : null;
    }

    private boolean isDevLoginEnabled() {
        Boolean devLoginEnabled = JNDI.lookup("devLoginEnabled");
        return (devLoginEnabled != null ? devLoginEnabled : false);
    }

    private boolean isSessionInitialized() {
        return sessionManager.getUser() != null;
    }

    private void initializeSession(Person user) {
        sessionManager.initializeSession(user);
    }

    private boolean isSessionCurrentUsers() {
        return sessionManager.getUser() != null && sessionManager.getUser().getEmail() != null
                && sessionManager.getUser().getEmail().equals(getUserEmail());
    }
}
```